# odoov9 override old api onchange

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want in res.partner model make onchange event on field parent_id. this field already have onchange event by old api, so i changed it`s value on XML to on_change=1 and added .py code

```
def onchange_parent_id(self):
    self.category_id = self.parent_id.category_id
    super(res_partner, self).onchange_parent_id(self)
```

after update, then i open contact form and changing parent_id, everything works as i want, but when i press save error occurrs

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

as i understand it occurrs becouse on create other method (_fields_sync) also calls this onchange_parent_id methot by 'old style'.

Maybe someone can advice me how to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `_fields_sync` calls `onchange_parent_id` with `context=[partner.id]` and this is the raison of the conversion error (api.py line 756).

**ODOO LOG**:
    WARNING ...: partner: res.partner(93,)
    api:756:context=[93]

**Python test**:

```
>>> from openerp.tools import frozendict
>>> context = [93]
>>> frozendict(context)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

> > TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
> >
> > > 

You can remove the old `onchange event` and create a new one (`onchange_parent_id_new`) without overriding `onchange_parent_id` method.

**Python**:

```
@api.model
@api.onchange('parent_id')
def onchange_parent_id_new(self):
  old_res = super(res_partner, self).onchange_parent_id(self.parent_id.id)
  if type(old_res) is dict and 'value' in old_res:
    for field, value in old_res.get('value').items():
      if hasattr(self, field):
        setattr(self, field, value)

  if self.parent_id:
      self.category_id = self.parent_id.category_id
```

**XML**:

```
<record id="view_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.partner.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="parent_id" position="replace">
        <field name="parent_id"/>
    </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: i have rewrited function: `@api.onchange('parent_id')
    def onchange_parent_id(self, parent_id=None):
        old_res = super(res_partner, self).onchange_parent_id(self.parent_id.id) 
     if type(old_res) is dict and old_res.has_key('value'):
            for field, value in old_res.get('value').items():
                if hasattr(self, field):
                    setattr(self, field, value)
        if self.parent_id:
            self.category_id = self.parent_id.category_id
        return {'value': {}} `  error `TypeError: onchange_parent_id() takes at most 2 arguments (6 given)`

Comment: @Zilvinas You need to convert old API calls to to new API signature using `@api.model`.Check my update I hope it will be useful.

Comment: thanks, this solution with new function name working.